# Velocity check if Map has a key with null value

Tags: velocity

I'm creating a velocity template to which I pass a map, and I want to get only the keys with values.

It is my code:

```
#set ($value = $map.get($key))
  #if($value != "")
    "$key": "$value",
  #end
```

- map.get(parameter) != null
- map.get(parameter) != ''

It prints: $value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try:

```
#if($value)
  "$key": "$value",
#end
```

It will filter out null and empty values.

Comment: But how to make a difference between null, empty and not defined at all ?

Comment: @Delphine It's detailed in [the docs](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#conditionals) : `$ref == $null` for null, `$ref == false` for false, `$ref == 0` for zero, `$ref == ''` for empty string, `$ref.size() == 0` for empty collection...

Comment: @Thanks. But i'm using AMZ API Gateway, and it seems different (strictmode ?). No way to differentiate `null` and `not defined`

Comment: @Delphine If the value you want to check is inside some container, the container may expose a `.contains(String key)` method. Otherwise, I dunno... In strict mode, the only thing you can do with an undefined var is `#if($undef)`, everything else will throw an exception, IMHO. And since this last statement doesn't do the distinction, I don't think it is possible.